# QGIS 2.6 automatically zooms to layer extent

Tags: qgis, zoom

Since I upgraded to QGIS 2.6 a mouse click (left or right) on any layer returns in a automatic zoom to the layers extent. Does anyone know how to switch off this function?

Comment: I am not experiencing this on Ubuntu or Windows with 2.6...

Comment: I too cannot reproduce, but I just realized a double r-click functions as zoom to layer. Just for the sake of it, make sure your mouse functionality is correct.